# PHP and AngularJS Associative Array loop

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, arrays

So I have a simple html file and this is the output:

[image]

**The html file code:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in items">
  <td ng-bind="key"></td>
  <td ng-bind="value"></td>
</tr>
```

**Angular file**

```
$scope.viewCart = function() {
  $('#cartModal').openModal();
  $http.get('../crud/cartCRUD/cart-data.php')
  .success(function(data) {
  $scope.items = data;
  })
}
```

**cart-data.php**

```
print json_encode($_SESSION['cart_items']);
```

My `$_SESSION['cart-items']` is an associative array containing of key(`product id`) => value (`quantity`)

If you access the php file directly using `print_r($_SESSION['cart-items'])`, you will get this:

```
Array
(
    [35] => 23
    [10] => 7
)
```

Meaning, the output from my html file is correct.

Now what I wanted to do is instead of showing the key and value in my `ng-repeat`, I want to get the product name from mysql database using the session array key(`product id`).

For now this is what I did

```
$statement = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id IN (".implode(',',array_keys($_SESSION['cart_items'])).")");

while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

print json_encode($data);
```

and in the html file:

```
  <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Price</th>
           <th>Quantity</th>           
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
           <td ng-bind="item.name"></td>
           <td ng-bind="item.price"></td>
           <td>HOW TO OUTPUT THE QUANTITY</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

This works though the problem is I cannot get the value of the key pair (quantity) anymore. Is there a proper way on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Inside de while statement you can use

```
$row["quantity"] = $_SESSION["cart-items"][$row["id"]];
```

Comment: you access to quantity using `item.quantity`?

Comment: Yes and I'm not getting any data. Console log says Undefined index cart-items